# How to get multiple selected images from canvas to php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, canvas

```js
function showimage(a){  
  
  /*$('#sinistra img').click(function () {
    var c = document.getElementById("screensketchCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var imgid = $(this).attr('id');
    var img = document.getElementById(imgid);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  });  */

 // checks if Html5 canvas is supported by the browser.
    if (!canvasSupported()) {
        alert("Screen sketch is not supported in this browser.");
    }

    // Access screen sketch object in and after document ready event
    var screenSketch = $("#screensketchCanvas").data("fp-screensketch");

    // local sketch image file.
    //var imageUrl = "assets/images/ScreenSketchImage.JPG";
    if(a==2){
        var imageUrl = $("#hiddenScreenSketchImageUrl").val();
        screenSketch.LoadImage(imageUrl);
       
    }
    else{
         $('#sinistra img').click(function () {
            var imgid = $(this).attr('id').slice(3);
            var imageUrl = $("#hiddenScreenSketchImageUrl"+imgid).val();
            screenSketch.LoadImage(imageUrl);
        });       
    }
       
     //}    
    
    // upload sketch file on screenSketch for amendment.
   

    // setup Annotation click event, this will be called when user click on annotation number.
    screenSketch.OnAnnotationClick(AnnotationClickHandler);

    // setup Annotation remove event, this will be called when user will erase annotation number.
    screenSketch.OnAnnotationRemove(AnnotationRemoveHandler);

    // update drawing position on scroll 
    $(".fp-canvas-wrapper").scroll(function () { screenSketch.SetupCanvasPositioning(); });

    // update screen sketch toolbox tooltip with current selection.
    $("[data-fp-tool]").on("change", UpdateSelectedToolCaption);
}
   
$(function () {

    // checks if Html5 canvas is supported by the browser.
    if (!canvasSupported()) {
        alert("Screen sketch is not supported in this browser.");
    }

    // Access screen sketch object in and after document ready event
    var screenSketch = $("#screensketchCanvas").data("fp-screensketch");

    // local sketch image file.
    //var imageUrl = "assets/images/ScreenSketchImage.JPG";
    if(a==2){
        var imageUrl = $("#hiddenScreenSketchImageUrl").val();
        screenSketch.LoadImage(imageUrl);
       
    }
    else{
         $('#sinistra img').click(function () {
            var imgid = $(this).attr('id').slice(3);
            var imageUrl = $("#hiddenScreenSketchImageUrl"+imgid).val();
            screenSketch.LoadImage(imageUrl);
        });       
    }
       
     //}    
    
    // upload sketch file on screenSketch for amendment.
   

    // setup Annotation click event, this will be called when user click on annotation number.
    screenSketch.OnAnnotationClick(AnnotationClickHandler);

    // setup Annotation remove event, this will be called when user will erase annotation number.
    screenSketch.OnAnnotationRemove(AnnotationRemoveHandler);

    // update drawing position on scroll 
    $(".fp-canvas-wrapper").scroll(function () { screenSketch.SetupCanvasPositioning(); });

    // update screen sketch toolbox tooltip with current selection.
    $("[data-fp-tool]").on("change", UpdateSelectedToolCaption);
});

// checks if Html5 canvas is supported by the browser.
function canvasSupported() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    return (canvas.getContext);
}


function onSubmit() { 
    // Access screen sketch object
    var screenSketch = $("#screensketchCanvas").data("fp-screensketch");
    // get screen sketch amended object 
    var amendments = screenSketch.GetAmendments();

    //      amendments { 
    //      Annotations:[ { ID, Comment}] , // an array of Annotation object
    //      EncodedImageData : "jped encoded image stream"
    //      }

    // convert Annotations comments to your specific format.
    var annotations = amendments.Annotations;
    var comments = "";

    comments =  $("#soComments").val();

    for (index = 0; index < annotations.length; ++index) {
        comments += " [" + annotations[index].ID + "]: " + annotations[index].Comment + ".\r\n";
    }

    // use image steam within the page Or post it Server.
    var dataURL = amendments.EncodedImageData;

    // hide screen sketch editor
    $("#bodyContent").hide();

    // show output from screen sketch editor
    $("#screenSketchOutput").show();

    // setup screen sketch editor output
    $("#ssoComments").val(comments);
    $("#modifiedImage").attr("src", dataURL);
    $("#hiddenImageStream").val(dataURL);


    inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hdnimage"),
    arr = [];          
        for(var i=0, len=inputs.length; i<len; i++){
        if(inputs[i].type === "hidden"){alert(JSON.stringify($("#hiddenImageStream"+i).val(dataURL)));
          arr.push($("#hiddenImageStream"+i).val(dataURL));
        }
        }$("#hiddenImageStream").val(arr);

        //console.log(arr);return false;

    $("#myform").submit();

   // window.location = dataURL.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
}

// setup Annotation comment input controls when Annotation is added.
function AnnotationClickHandler(event, model) {

    var annotationBlock = $(".fp-annotation-input-block[data-annid='" + model.AnnotationId + "']");

    if (annotationBlock.length == 0) {
        var annotationTemplate = $(".fp-annotation-template").clone();
        annotationTemplate.removeClass("fp-annotation-template");
        annotationTemplate.attr("data-annid", model.AnnotationId);
        annotationTemplate.find(".fp-annotation-input-id").text(model.AnnotationId);
        annotationTemplate.find(".fp-annotation-input").val(model.AnnotationComments);
        annotationTemplate.find(".fp-annotation-input").attr("data-annid", model.AnnotationId);

        $(".fp-annotation-block").append(annotationTemplate);
    }
    else {
        $(".fp-annotation-input[data-annid='" + model.AnnotationId + "']").val(model.AnnotationComments);
    }
}

// hide Annotation comment input controls when Annotation is removed.
function AnnotationRemoveHandler(event, model) {
    
    $(".fp-annotation-input-block[data-annid='" + model.AnnotationId + "']").remove();
}

// update Annotation comment when user select's another control.
$(document).on("focusout", ".fp-annotation-input", function () {
    var screenSketch = $("#screensketchCanvas").data("fp-screensketch");
    if (screenSketch == undefined)
        return;

    var annotationId = $(this).attr("data-annid");
    var annotationContent = $(this).val();

    if (annotationId > 0) {
        screenSketch.Annotation.UpdateAnnotation(annotationId, annotationContent);

    }

    return false;
});

// update screen sketch toolbox tooltip
function UpdateSelectedToolCaption() {
    var toolType = $(this).data("fp-tool");

    switch (toolType) {
        case "pen":
            $(".fp-caption-selection").text("(Pen)");
            break;
        case "eraser":
            $(".fp-caption-selection").text("(Eraser)");
            break;
        case "annotation":
            $(".fp-caption-selection").text("(Add / edit text annotation)");
            break;
        case "move":
            $(".fp-caption-selection").text("(Move Items)");
            break;        
    }
}
```

```html
{extends "main.tpl"}
{block "pagetitle"}Request Amendments{/block}

{block "extrajs"}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/fabric.js-1.1.0/all.1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/Scripts/ScreenSketch-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/Scripts/ScreenSketchPage.js"></script>  
{/block}

{block "extracss"}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/floorplans.css">
{/block}  

{block "welcome"}{/block}
{block "maincontent"}  
<literal>
<style>
.navbar {    
    display: none !important;
}
#main-container, #main-content {
    margin-top: -33px !important;
}
</style>
<script>
function sendfile(e){  //alert($('#img1').attr('src'));
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        var imgObject = $('#img'+i).attr('src'); 
       // alert(imgObject);
        //var imgSource1 = imgObject.src;
        $("#hiddenScreenSketchImageUrl"+i).val(imgObject);
       
     } 
}

</script>
</literal>
    
    <div style="background-color: #2a2b2d; margin: -4px -20px 5px;">
        {if $listfilename|count}
        {assign var=val value=0}
        {foreach $listfilename as $fnm}
            {assign var=val value=$val+1}
            <span style="width:200px; height:200px;padding-right: 0px;margin-left: 22px;" id="sinistra">
                <img src="{$fnm}" id="img{$val}" name="img{$val}" class="mg" style="width:200px; height:200px;" onclick="showimage(this)">
            </span>
        {/foreach} 
        {else}      
            <span style="width:200px; height:200px;padding-right: 0px;margin-left: 22px" onclick="sendfile()">
            <img src="{$imgurl}" id="img1" style="width:200px; height:200px;" onclick="showimage(2)">
            </span>
        {/if}
    </div>

    <div id="bodyContent" style="background-color: #6c99dc;margin: 0px -20px 0px;">    
        <div id="headerContainer" data-role="header" style="display: none;">
            <h1>
                Request Amendments</h1>
        </div>        
            <div id="floorplansContainer" class="fp-canvas-editor">
            <div class="fp-canvas-wrapper" style="width: 940px; height: 900px;">
                <canvas class="fp-canvas" id="screensketchCanvas" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;"
                    data-fp-canvas="first">
                </canvas>                
            </div>
            <form action="/?page=clientorder&amp;action=saveamendment" id="myform" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="settings-wrapper" style="padding-left: 10px !important;">
                <div class="fp-canvas-settings">
                    <div>
                          <!--Screen sketch zoom buttons-->
                        <div class="fp-toolbar fp-toolbar-item fp-zoom-wrapper">
                            <input type="button" value="Reset zoom" class="fp-zoom-item fp-zoomResetBtn" data-fp-zoom="zoomreset"/>                                                    
                            <input type="button"  value="Zoom +" class="fp-zoom-item fp-zoomInBtn" data-fp-zoom="zoomin" />
                            <input type="button" value="Zoom -" class="fp-zoom-item fp-zoomOutBtn" data-fp-zoom="zoomout" />                                                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <BR/>
                    <div class="fp-toolbar fp-toolbox">
                        <div class="fp-toolbar-item fp-tools-caption">
                             <input type="button" value="Reset Pan" class="fp-zoom-item fp-zoomOutBtn" data-fp-tool="pen" /><br><br>
                            <label>
                                <span class="fp-tools-caption-item fp-caption-Tools"><b>Tools</b></span> 
                                <span class="fp-tools-caption-item fp-caption-selection">(Pen)</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>                      
                          <!--Screen sketch Toolbox -->
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type="radio" id="penTool" name="controls" class="fp-toolbox-item" data-fp-tool="pen"
                                value="toggleDrawing" checked="checked">
                            <label for="penTool">
                                <span class="fp-label fp-icon pen" title="Pen"></span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" id="eraserTool" name="controls" class="fp-toolbox-item" data-fp-tool="eraser"
                                value="toggleEraser">
                            <label for="eraserTool">
                                <span class="fp-label fp-icon eraser" title="Eraser"></span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" id="annotationTool" name="controls" class="fp-toolbox-item" data-fp-tool="annotation"
                                value="toggleAnnotation">
                            <label for="annotationTool">
                                <span class="fp-label fp-icon text" title="Annotation"></span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" id="pickerTool" name="controls" class="fp-toolbox-item" data-fp-tool="move"
                                value="togglePicker">
                            <label for="pickerTool">
                                <span class="fp-label fp-icon move" title="Move"></span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="controls" class="SS-tool active" data-type="pan" id="panTool">
                            <label for="panTool" style="margin:2px 10px 2px 2px">                        <span class="fp-label fp-icon pan" title="Pan"></span>                    </label>                           
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <BR/>
                    <!--Screen sketch color selection panel -->
                    <div class="fp-toolbar fp-toolbox-settings">
                        <div class="fp-toolbar fp-toolbox-settings-caption">
                            <label for="penColourRed">
                                <b>Colour</b></label>
                            <fieldset class="fp-toolbox-settings-item">
                                <input type="radio" id="penColourRed" name="colourselector" data-fp-pencolour="red"
                                    class="fp-toolbox-settings-item fp-penColourSelector" value="red" checked="checked" />
                                <label for="penColourRed">
                                    <span class="fp-label fp-icon red" title="red">&nbsp;</span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="radio" id="penColourGreen" name="colourselector" data-fp-pencolour="green"
                                    class="fp-toolbox-settings-item fp-penColourSelector" value="green" />
                                <label for="penColourGreen">
                                    <span class="fp-label fp-icon green" title="green">&nbsp;</span></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="penColourBlue" name="colourselector" data-fp-pencolour="blue"
                                    class="fp-toolbox-settings-item fp-penColourSelector" value="blue" />
                                <label for="penColourBlue">
                                    <span class="fp-label fp-icon blue" title="blue">&nbsp;</span></label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <BR/>
                        <div class="fp-toolbar fp-toolbox-settings-item">
                         <!--Screen sketch pen thickness selection panel -->
                            <label for="penThickness">
                                <b>Thickness</b></label>
                            <input type="range" name="penThickness" class="fp-penThickness" data-fp-penthickness="2"
                                value="2" min="1" max="10">
                        </div>
                        <div><b>Your annotation – please use annotation tool above marked with(T)</b></div>
                        <div class="fp-annotation-block" style="height:100px; border: 0px !important;">
                        <div class="fp-annotation-input-block fp-annotation-template">
                             <span class="fp-annotation-input-id" style="float: left; width:25px;"></span>
                             <input type="text" name="annotation" id="annotation" class="fp-annotation-input" style="width: 80%;"
                                placeholder="Include annotation for sequence" title="Include annotation for sequence" />
                        </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <BR/>
                      <!--Screen sketch comments -->
                    <div class="fp-toolbar fp-canvas-notes">
                        <span class="fp-canvas-notes-caption"><b>Your Comments/notes</b><br /></span>  
                         <div class="" style="height:220px; ">
                            <textarea id="soComments" name="soComments" cols="27" rows="10"></textarea>
                        <div style="text-align: right;">
                         <input type="button" onclick="onSubmit()" value="Submit" style="text-align: right;" /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>         
                    {if $listfilename|count}
                    {assign var=hidval value=0}           
                    {foreach $listfilename as $fn}
                         {assign var=hidval value=$hidval+1}
                         <span id="sinistra1">
                         <input type="hidden" id="hiddenScreenSketchImageUrl{$hidval}" name="hiddenScreenSketchImageUrl{$hidval}" value="{$fn}" runat="server" class="hdbtn"/>
                         <input type="hidden" id="hiddenScreenSketchImagename" name="hiddenScreenSketchImagename{$hidval}" value="{$filename}" runat="server" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenImageStream{$hidval}" name="hiddenImageStream[]" class="hdnimage" runat="server" />
                    {/foreach}
                    {else}                   
                    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenScreenSketchImageUrl" name="hiddenScreenSketchImageUrl" value="{$imgurl}" runat="server" class="hdbtn" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenScreenSketchImagename" name="hiddenScreenSketchImagename" value="{$filename}" runat="server" /> 
                    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenImageStream" name="hiddenImageStream" runat="server" />
                    {/if}
                    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenoid" name="hiddenoid" value="{$oid}" runat="server" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenftamd" name="hiddenftamd" value="{$ftamd}" runat="server" />
                   
                    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenAnnotations" runat="server" />                                  
                </div>
            </div><!--settings-wrapper-->                   
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="screenSketchOutput" style="display: none;">
       <div width="50%" style="width: 67%;margin-top: -58px; background-color: #c9e6c9;">
            <h5>
                Thank you for submitting your brochure / window card amendments, these have been received by Floorplanz and your amended brochure / window card will be returned to you shortly.
            </h5>    
        </div> 
    </div>
    </form>
{/block}
```

I have a pdf file having multiple images and each selected image is displaying in a canvas after click on the image but problem is that each selected multiple images is unable to get in php. Basically i want to get all selected images in php from canvas. For your reference i am sharing you screenshoot, please check.[image]

Comment: Post the code please.

Comment: hi Simone, fyi i added code please check, it is develope with smarty and javascript and php

Comment: That's a lot of code - what have you tried to find a solution?

Comment: i want to get both two images in php base 64 format from canvas javascript.